# Несколько записей в одном запросе

Tags: sql

Нужно выбрать несколько записей из двух связанных таблиц в одном запросе. Для двух записей делаю так:

```
$query = 'SELECT t1.title, t2.type content_store 
          FROM content t1 
          LEFT JOIN content_store t2 ON t1.id = ' . $id. ' 
          WHERE t2.id = ' . $id;
```

Вроде работает. Но нужно добавить в выбор еще один столбец `alias` из таблицы `content`. Как я могу это сделать? И будет ли такой запрос, и правда, работать быстрее трех отдельных запросов?

Comment: начало должно выглядеть где то так `SELECT t1.title, t2.type, t1.alias content_store

Comment: Из вашего запроса совершенно не понятно как таблицы связаны.

Comment: По идее должно быть что-то типа: SELECT t1.title, t2.type, t1.alias FROM content t1 LEFT JOIN content_store t2 ON t1.id = t2.id  WHERE t2.id = ...

Comment: Так и есть, всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Время на запрос включает не только его выполнение, но и его путешествие по сети. Как правило, путешествие по сети и занимает большую часть времени в отличие от выполнения(сервер sql прекрасно перемалывает тонны информации). Поэтому как правило один сложный запрос гораздо выгоднее нескольких менее затратных запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Для обозначенной задачи запрос можно оформить примерно так:

```
SELECT t1.title, t2.type, t1.alias 
FROM content t1 
LEFT JOIN content_store t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id = ..
```

И да, данный запрос будет работать быстрее, чем несколько отдельных запросов.